# Registering a child in the process that initiated the start_child call

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I have a logic module that tells a supervisor to start child processes. I need to store those childrens pid in the logic modules state. But I also need to update a childs pid if the supervisor restarts it.

So I can't use the return value pid from the start_child call, since that will only give me the pid on the first start, not the restarts. Right now I make the child process call a register function (updates state with new pid) in the logic module from the childs init function. That way the logic module can update the pid in its state whenever a process is restarted. The logic module is a gen_server and I'm doing a cast when i register the child process.

Can anyone see a problem with this and are there any other more "proper" way of doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One problem is that you have the `ChildPid` and the child might be dead by now. So sending it a message through a `cast` will mean the message is lost. And through a `call` you will crash yourself with an `{'EXIT', noproc}` unless you catch it out of the `call`. Your solution must take into account that a `Pid` might be long gone the instant you send a message. Usually by ignoring that the message is lost, by crashing yourself, or by remedying the problem and then go on.

There are a couple of options. This is a loose list:

- Do as you do. Let the childs register themselves.
- Let the logic module have a `monitor` on the child. That way you know if it dies.
- Use *Erlang Solutions* **gproc** module: https://github.com/esl/gproc which gives you a neat interface to an ETS table keeping track of the information. Note that you can look up a pid in gproc and *await* its arrival if the process is just restarting.
- Use `supervisor:which_children` to find the relevant child.
- Roll your own ETS table as a variant of `gproc`
- *local* names have to be atoms, but *globally registered* names can be any term (they are stored internally in a ETS table looking somewhat like gproc's, see the **global_name_server** in `kernel/stdlib`). Use the global structure to track the pids in question.